# SwiftUI Drag events how do restrict to detect only horizontal/vertical scrolls

Tags: list, scrollview, swiftui, drag

I have List (vertically scrolled) with nested ScrollView (or View that has dragging attached to it). I would like to have nested view **onDrag()** to be detected only on horizontal scrolling and not on vertical one. Vertical scrolling should be propagated to wrapper List.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the following demo of horizontal scroll view inside vertical list should be working, and it is, unless List for now has known "refresh" defect. So... I decided to post it just for demo... maybe with next SwiftUI/iOS update it will be fixed automatically.

Also I provided variant of horizontal scroll view inside vertical scroll view, as a workaround to `List` issue. Hope any of those would be helpful.

So, demo code for "vertical drag anywhere propagated to vertical scrolling container, horizontal drag works only in horizontal scroll view"

A - Working variant of `body` based on vertical `ScrollView` (to replace in below module)

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach (0..<20, id: \.self) { i in
                VStack {
                    self.rowItem(index: i)
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

B - "Working" variant with List (having refresh issue)

```
struct TestScrollInList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach (0..<20, id: \.self) { i in
                self.rowItem(index: i)
            }
        }
    }

    func rowItem(index i: Int) -> AnyView {
        if i % 2 == 0 {
            return AnyView(self.plainItem(index: i))
        } else {
            return AnyView(self.scrollableItem(index: i))
        }
    }

    func plainItem(index i: Int) -> some View {
        Text("Plain item \(i)")
    }

    func scrollableItem(index i: Int) -> some View {
        ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<10) { j in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .fill(j % 2 == 0 ? Color.green : Color.yellow)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: 110)
    }
}

struct TestScrollInList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestScrollInList()
    }
}
```